# Multiple selects in a procedure not evaluating

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure as below

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CNT int =33, 
            @mlogin VARCHAR (1) = 'm',
            @concusers INT ='33' ;

    SELECT 
        @CNT = COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        USRINF u, usrdpf usr   
    WHERE 
        u.userid = usr.userid 
        AND u.LOGOUT_TIME IS NULL 
        AND u.USERID = @USERID ;

    SELECT 
        @mlogin = mlogin, @concusers = concusers 
    FROM 
        usrdpf upf    
    WHERE  
        upf.USERID = @USERID ;

    PRINT @mlogin;-----m
    PRINT @concusers;-----33
    PRINT @CNT ; ----0

    IF (@mlogin = 'Y' AND @CNT < @concusers)
```

The second select statement is not executing, after execution I can see `@mlogin` and `@concusers` value as the one i have assigned as default ie 'm' and ''33' respectively whereas @cnt  is 0  why so ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Just check usrdpf table have data for given user id

Comment: @Mansoor yeah it do have data for the userid i am providing

Comment: can you provide data for that user id.As it is in your table

Comment: `@CNT=0` says - there are no rows for user_id you're providing.

Comment: @IvanStarostin it returns count 2 when i run the query explicitly.

Comment: Add full source of SP. With @USERID declaration and all assignments.